# Global hooks JAVA LINUX (Ubuntu)

Tags: java, qt, ubuntu, hook, global

I want to hook into another GUI app (probably using Qt).
I want to know, when some button is ready to click and etc.
My app technology is JAVA, my OS is Ubuntu.

Michal.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the button thing, but the most commom way of interacting with other desktop applications if there is no public API is using the `Robot` class. With a `Robot` you have control over the cursor (point&click) as well as keyboard input.

[Javadoc java.awt.Robot](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html)

I don't know which application you want to hook into, but some expose data and methods via DBUS. It would be less costly.

Answer (score 0):

I seriously doubt you can do this. Especially from java. Unless the app you're trying to control has some public API, or can be controlled with dbus.

This sounds like a job for some native hack via either X11 apis or something from Qt.